# Implementing magnific lightbox to tumblr issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently having some issues trying to implement the magnific lightbox to my tumblr blog single photo post page. After reading around seems like my best shot was to try to integrate the magnific lightbox. Would much appreciate any help on this.

Quick note: I have no experience in javascript language, mainly only css and html so would much appreciate if any answers could be as descriptive as possible, maybe even some step by step on where I am going wrong with this. I know it's a lot to ask but would much appreciate some beginners patience, thanks :)

```
     The HTML

        {block:Photo}
            <div class="single-content">
                <figure class="photo-post-wrapper">
                    <div class="photo-lightbox">
                        <a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"><img data-interchange="{PhotoURL-500}, {PhotoURL-HighRes}"></a>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </div>
            {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
        {/block:Photo}


    The CSS
    .photo-lightbox a { 
        -moz-cursor: zoom-in; -webkit-cursor: zoom-in; cursor: zoom-in;
    }
    .photo-lightbox a:hover { 
    opacity: 0.7; 
    } 
    .photo-post-wrapper {
    margin: 2em 0; 
    text-align: center;
    }
    .photo-post-wrapper img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* Magnific Popup CSS Below (Just the copy and pasted css code provided by magnific its pretty long so i'll just add  the link  */


    //The script I have added before </body> and after </footer> for magnific lightbox.
    {block:PermalinkPage}
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.photo-lightbox').magnificPopup({
                delegate: 'a',
                type: 'image',
                tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
                mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
                gallery: {
                    enabled: true,
                    navigateByImgClick: true,
                    preload: [0,1]
                }
            });
        });
```

Not sure if it's the issue but everything is inline, have not linked any external files.

link to magnific css

https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/blob/master/dist/magnific-popup.css

EDIT:
Also just wanted to add, I am considering to create a pure css lightbox if this proves to be too problematic for me to setup, anybody know if pure css lightboxes are good idea or not ?

Comment: Example to the site with the issue? I would imagine writing your own lightbox to be a heck of a lot harder to do that setting up `magnific-popup`.

Comment: Hey @mikedidthis, thanks for your initial concern with this, got a solution and seems to work fine. Thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this. (Tumblr doesn't usually have lightbox for single photo posts, only for panorama and photosets) which means you either have to integrate an external lightbox like what I was trying to do with magnific lightbox, or you put in some code that enables the tumblr lightbox to function on single photo posts. Heres what I did and it sorted out the issue really really easily.

```
<script class="inline_embed" type="text/javascript">
var domain = document.domain,
photo_{PostID} = [{
    "width": "{PhotoWidth-HighRes}",
    "height": "{PhotoHeight-HighRes}",
    "low_res": "{PhotoURL-250}",
    "high_res": "{PhotoURL-HighRes}"
}];

function event_is_alt_key(e) {
    return ((!e && window.event && (window.event.metaKey || window.event.altKey)) || (e && (e.metaKey || e.altKey)));
};

document.getElementById('photo_{PostID}').onclick = function (e) {
    if (event_is_alt_key(e)) return true;

    window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init(photo_{PostID});

    return false;
}
```

Now this next bit which are a few simple instructions I will quote from @Jayowend since he is the one who came up with this easy solution.

"In the Edit HTML screen of your theme's Customize, search for the {Block:Photo} and inside, look for the  so it will resemble something like this:

Once you've done that, copy the modified javascript code block at the top and paste it after the image code, and save. When you click an image post, it should bring up the Lightbox that tumblr uses for photosets and show the vignette background."

The original SO post I got this from was from here:

[Tumblr Photo/Photoset popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406370/tumblr-photo-photoset-popup)

Unfortunately I had to post this question as i was trying to figure out how to get magnific lightbox to work for the last 2 days which I'm sure is not hard for somebody with some basic JS skills, however for any amateurs like me, maybe this can save you time by just altering some code and using tumblr's lightbox instead like i did for single photo posts.

Other than that, sorry that there is no conclusion to the magnific lightbox, but may real goal was to have a lightbox for single photo posts and atleast that was achieved. hope the alternate solution works just as well for anybody else trying to get a lightbox for single photo posts. :)

Also Big UP to @Jayowend with his/her easy fix to getting lightbox working on single photo posts, all credit goes to @Jayowend.