# Tumblr Lightbox with Infinite scroll: appended photos lose embedded script tag

Tags: jquery, lightbox, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I'm doing a hack of a [tumblr theme](http://adorablethemes.com/theme/copycat) to make it more of a responsive photo-gallery rather than opening up a post and displaying a bunch of notes and such that I don't care about.  I noticed that photosets open up in a lightbox and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406370/tumblr-photo-photoset-popup/24318262#24318262) which worked for applying that lightbox to standard photos.

This all works great with a paginated gallery, but I wanted it to work with the theme's [infinite scrolling](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll).  However, when I turned that on, it added the new photo-posts fine, but it completely omitted the embedded javascript that controls the click event for the lightbox.

For example, here's a div for one of the working photos:

```
<article class="post photo" style="position: absolute; left: 1064px; top: 807px;">       
<!--Modified to open photos in lightbox-->
<figure class="photo-content" width="250" height="354">

<a href="http://charlie-bowater.deviantart.com/art/Shallows-566690276"><img class="photo-post-photo" src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/ae09f12fce484f6265753eb05da0c3ee/tumblr_nwmbgfE1OW1tvnxcqo1_250.jpg" id="photo_131890640965" data-retina="http://36.media.tumblr.com/ae09f12fce484f6265753eb05da0c3ee/tumblr_nwmbgfE1OW1tvnxcqo1_500.jpg" alt=""></a>
</figure>
<script class="inline_embed" type="text/javascript">
    var domain = document.domain,
    photo_131890640965 = [{
        "width": "700",
        "height": "990",
        "low_res": "http://40.media.tumblr.com/ae09f12fce484f6265753eb05da0c3ee/tumblr_nwmbgfE1OW1tvnxcqo1_250.jpg",
        "high_res": "http://36.media.tumblr.com/ae09f12fce484f6265753eb05da0c3ee/tumblr_nwmbgfE1OW1tvnxcqo1_1280.jpg"
    }];

    function event_is_alt_key(e) {
        return ((!e && window.event && (window.event.metaKey || window.event.altKey)) || (e && (e.metaKey || e.altKey)));
    };

    document.getElementById('photo_131890640965').onclick = function (e) {
        if (event_is_alt_key(e)) return true;

        window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init(photo_131890640965);

        return false;
    }
</script>
<!--End of Lightbox Modification-->
</article>
```

And here's one added by infinite scroll:

```
<article class="post photo" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1163px;">        
<!--Modified to open photos in lightbox-->
<figure class="photo-content" width="250" height="309">

<a href=""><img class="photo-post-photo" src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/80918d59b37dfa13dbae2004b6a6345a/tumblr_nwromsbytb1rqat58o1_250.jpg" id="photo_131890115135" data-retina="http://41.media.tumblr.com/80918d59b37dfa13dbae2004b6a6345a/tumblr_nwromsbytb1rqat58o1_500.jpg" alt=""></a>
</figure>

<!--End of Lightbox Modification-->
</article>
```

So the infinite scroll version seems to have everything *but* the embedded javascript that initializes the lightbox for each photo.

**Things I've considered:**

- Script tag is missing a crucial id/class: however the only tag infinite scroll looks for is the '.post' class, which the script tag is inside of
- Maybe it's pulling a template from elsewhere: however the comment I put in there is being copied over as well as the id on img, so some of my modifications are present
- jQuery avoids copying script tags: however I dug into the code and found infinite scroll runs on `jQuery.load()` and `jQuery.children()`, I tested both of these in a small proof of concept on jsfiddle and found that it should be able to retrieve script tags through that method fine.

So I'm more or less out of ideas on why it's not adding the script tag to new posts created by infinite scroll.  Is there any ideas on what might be going wrong, or perhaps a better way to handle this?